# How to get system data and make unique my application for the OS

Tags: java, swing, operating-system, desktop-application

I want to know how to get a unique identifier of the PC which my application installed. I followed some questions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823394/how-to-get-unique-identifier-of-system).But I couldn't make use of it. Please let me know how to do it in Java  with sample code or any useful link.(At least how to get system details in Java) Thanks

Comment: Why could you not make use of it? One answer has all the code there.

Comment: Please show what you tried based on [How to GET Unique identifier of system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823394/how-to-get-unique-identifier-of-system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that not stable idea with unstable output, noting there guaratee that you received correct Computer & User Informations, an unique identifier of the PC and more confident results returns computers in Intranet (not Interner) behind HW FireWall

problems:

- IP can be chanded
- MAC can be Alliased

Novell, AD can add detailed UserInfo, and some Computers (all HP/Compaq) doesn't returns HW configurations

```
private void getPcInfo() {
    Enumeration<?> interfaces = null;
    try {
        PcLogName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        InetAddress local = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        InetAddress[] all_local = InetAddress.getAllByName(local.getHostName());
        LinkedList<InetAddress> list = new LinkedList<InetAddress>();
        //System.out.println("PcLogName " + PcLogName);
        //System.out.println("PcLogName " + list);
        try {
            interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            ////System.out.println("NetworkInterface " + interfaces);
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GuiFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface card = (NetworkInterface) interfaces.nextElement();
            ////System.out.println("NetworkInterface NetCard " + card);
            Enumeration<?> addresses = card.getInetAddresses();
            ////System.out.println("NetCard Name " + addresses);
            if (addresses == null) {
                continue;
            }
            while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress address = (InetAddress) addresses.nextElement();
                list.add(address);
                //System.out.println("Add Address : " + address);
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("IP's Address " + list);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GuiFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    PcLogUser = System.getProperty("user.name");
    //System.out.println("PcLogUser : " + PcLogUser);
    WinUser = System.getenv("USER");
    //System.out.println("WinUser : " + WinUser);
    WinDsn = System.getenv("USERDOMAIN");
    //System.out.println("WinDsn : " + WinDsn);
    WinUserName = System.getenv("USERNAME");
    //System.out.println("WinUserName : " + WinUserName);
    WinPath = System.getenv("USERPROFILE");
    //System.out.println("WinPath : " + WinPath);
    ComputerName = System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
    //System.out.println("ComputerName : " + ComputerName);
    PcInfo = System.getenv("System Model");
    //System.out.println("PcInfo : " + PcInfo);        
}
```

how to get MAC for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362763/regular-expression-to-work-on-different-locales/7363017#7363017)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mac address of the system, each system has unique mac address.

```
/*
* Get NetworkInterface for the current host and then read the
* hardware address.
*/

NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);

    if (ni != null) {
        byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
        if (mac != null) {

        /*
        * Extract each array of mac address and convert it to hexa with the
        * following format 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E.
        */
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
            }
        } else {
        System.out.println("Address doesn't exist or is not accessible.");
        }
    } else {

        System.out.println("Network Interface for the specified address is not found.");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still new for these things. Would you let me know what "address" is meant in first line of your code?NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);  also can I make sure whether the user reinstall the system, the code doesnot change and id is 100% unique for any pc?

Comment: @Aash, `address` is the ip of the system, this will be a InetAddress object. 

`//InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
   InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.46.53");`

Comment: @Aash: If the user doesn't change his networking hardware, and doesn't spoof the MAC address, it will remain the same for a given "PC". That said, trying to track the user in a way he can't easily foil sounds very very shady to me, and I think I'm going to go and randomise my MAC on every logon.

Comment: This doesn't work as if you have several network cards (dual Ethernet motherboards, Wifi, VPN, VmWare virtual adapters), you get several MAC addresses. You can get all, but depending on which are enabled, you can get more or less MAC addresses. CPU id have others problems as not accessible from Java and several PC manufacturers not set it. I recommend getting the Hard Disk serial id by performing "dir" on Windows in a `Process`, parsing the result and getting this information like:
 El volumen de la unidad C es WINDOWS
 El número de serie del volumen es: E22B-1261 <-- The ID

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments :) I got many things from your comments. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the simple and effective way is getting Hard Disk ID. On Windows parse "dir" output. This is stable until user replaces de Hard Drive and reinstall OS but it's not perfect.

Comment: Are you sure these identifiers do not collide? As it is only 32-bit number, I would fear that there are multiple drives with the same ID. If somebody wants to use it as identification of PC (for example sending the data over network), not only for detection if the app data has moved, there could be a problem.

Comment: Yes, could be a collision. Depends on the policy follow assigning that ID. I don't know this policy so can't assure there is no collision. I used in some applications with very little users (<100) and works fine. Over the Internet could be a problem.